# How to enable presistent proxy_arp

Tags: networking, proxy

I'm having trouble finding a way to make the following command persistent on my debian router

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp
```

I did find that I can do it for ip forwarding in the File: /etc/sysctl.conf 
I would just need to uncomment `ipv4.ip_forward=1` but I'm not sure how to do it for `proxy_arp` would it just be `ipv4.proxy_arp=1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it two different ways. 
First, you can target a specific interface (enp3so in this case):

```
# The next line enables proxy arp for IPv4 on the main Ethernet port only
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.proxy_arp = 1
```

The other way is more generic and will apply to all interfaces:

```
# Apply proxy arp for anyone
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1
```

Then sudo sysctl -p and you are good